# Fix Menu on Left Side and Right Side Content Change on Menu Option Click MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a MVC application in which on the Left Side Menu will load first time when the user Login into the application and on click of any of the Menu Option only Right side Content will display(Will Call the Action Method).

I have achieved it using Partial Views. Is it good to create whole application on Partial Views or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: please explain your problem more...

Comment: @karan On the left side there will be a menu with 100 options and on the click of that menu I want to call the Url on the right side. I do not want to refresh the whole page, only want to call the Url on the Right side.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to load the page for which the link is clicked, in an asynchronous way. You can do that using jQuery ajax methods.

So first, mark your links with a css class name so we can use that as the jQuery selector to wire up the ajaxfied load behavior. You should also has a content page to which we will load the result of the ajax call.

```
<div>
  <div id="leftPane">
     <a href="@Url.Action("About","Home")" class="alink">About</a>
     <a href="@Url.Action("Contact","Home")" class="alink">Contact</a>
     <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")" class="alink">Index</a>
  <div>
  <div id="rightPane">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can listen to the click event on those link, use jQuery load method to get the content of those action method and update the rightPane's innerHtml

```
$(function(){

   $("a.alink").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#rightPane").load($(this).attr("href"));
   });

});
```

With proper css, you can keep the leftPane to the left side of the container and rightPane to the right side of that.